# Anyone can explain me why this error "expected identifier before '(' token" is popping out in my code?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, syntax-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 2
typedef struct data{
    char name[20], address[20];
    int number;
}person;

int main()
{
    person p[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("Type the person's name %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%20s", p[i].name);
    }
    printf("%c", (p + 1)->(name + 1));//where the error happens
    return 0; 
}
```

Well, what I'm trying to do is print out the second letter of the second structure array, but as you can see the error is pointed out and I didn't understand why that's happening, since if "printf("%c", (p + 1)->name[1])" is written down instead of the stretch up there it works, and I
took the fact the pointer's name is a pointer that points to the first address of the array into
account, hence the stretch of code "name + 1", since name is a pointer as well. Then, why this's happening? And which relation it has with the error written down in the Title?

Comment: Use array notation for clarity (for yourself as much as others). `p[1].name[1]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kaylum! In my case, i just used such thing to warm up my knowledge about pointers and its behaviors as well!

Comment: after the `->` token it is mandatory to use a field name, not a left parenthesis, as you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side of the `->` operator is expected to be an identifier specifying a field name in a struct or union.  You instead have a parenthesized expression.

What you have should be written as:

```
(p + 1)->name + 1
```

However this expression has type `char *`, not `char` as the `%c` format specifier expects, so it should actually be:

```
*((p + 1)->name + 1)
```

Or better still, using array indexing notation instead of explicit pointer arithmetic and dereferencing:

```
p[1].name[1]
```

Comment: Well, "*((p + 1)->name + 1)" worked but I didn't understand how it worked...can you clarify for me, please? thanks in advance!

Comment: @MatteusGutëmberg What part are you confused about?

Comment: this one "*((p + 1)->name + 1)"!

Comment: @MatteusGutëmberg The answer explains what it is.  What specifically about that expression isn't making sense?

Comment: Well, why you dereferenced all the expression up there instead of just this stretch *(p + 1), I couldn't understand that!

Comment: @MatteusGutëmberg `(p + 1)->name` is an array with type `char [20]`.  Adding 1 to that, i.e. `(p + 1)->name + 1` has type `char *` and points to index 1 of the `name` member.  So now to get the value of that member you need to dereference the result of that expression, i.e. `*((p + 1)->name + 1)`